# Validation on caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, input, caliburn.micro

I implement my first application with the caliburn micro framework. I don't find any good information about data validation. Can anyone tell me how I realize the validation in caliburn micro? Is there a easy and elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might help http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=71

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small plugin for CM to enable fluent builder-style validation. Feel free to use it: https://github.com/AIexandr/Caliburn.Micro.Validation
Example of usage:

```
  // Constructor
  public OrderLine()
  {
    AddValidationRule(() => Number).Condition(() => string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Number)).Message("Please fill the product name");
  }
```